# windows 10 start menu search - file content?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-search, productivity

I have my docx files indexed includings its contents (index settings in windows 10). I want my start menu search to also use file contents of that indexed docx files.

How can I do that?

Comment: I thought that was already the default method for searching in the Start Menu. What build of Windows 10 are you running? Are searches in your Start Menu NOT finding based on the contents of documents? You haven't actually described a problem yet, just hinted at one. Please use the EDIT button to clarify your question.

Comment: @music2myear What do clarify? No, the now updated version Windows 10 doesn't start menu search doesn't search in file's contents. That I want to have fixed. Windows Version 1803 .

Comment: Windows 10 is currently at release 1809, not 1803. Please confirm what your indexing options are from the Start Menu. When searching in the Start Menu, there are three dots in the upper-right. Click these to open a menu and view the current indexing options.

Comment: @music2myear I now updated to 1809. The problem still exists. Yes, i can confirm that my directory having the docx files is included. Yes on docx i have selected to also index the contents. Still: Windows just offers to open windows explorer for search and doesn't show docx results containing my search term.